# Change parameters On error in vb6

Tags: vba, vb6

I am working with vb6 and automating some tasks to be performed across a large number of spreadsheets.

The issue is setting my worksheet.  Most of the syntax on the workbooks I am working with is the same however there are some where the sheets have different names.

Currently using

```
for x = 2 to cellcount
    set worksheet = workbook.sheets("*typical sheet name*")
    *rest of code
```

I'd like to set up something like this

psuedo-code

```
for x = 2 to cellcount
    On error goto errorhandler
    set worksheet= workbook.sheets("*typical sheet name*")
    Errorhandler:
    set worksheet= workbook.sheets("*secondary sheet name*")
    *rest of code
```

How can this be done in vb6?

Comment: cannot you access them by number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use errors to control the flow of the logic, instead look at all the available names and select the one you want:

```
Function GetBestMatchingSheet() As Worksheet
    For Each GetBestMatchingSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Select Case LCase$(GetBestMatchingSheet.Name)
            Case "typical sheet name", "secondary sheet name", "third name"
                Exit Function
        End Select

        Set GetBestMatchingSheet = Nothing
    Next
End Function

...

dim foundSheet As Worksheet
set foundSheet = GetBestMatchingSheet()

If not foundSheet is Nothing then msgbox foundSheet.Name
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. I can certainly see the advantage of defining variable before an error is thrown. This is a little tricky in my application but I can appreciate the efficiency of it.